# nginx/1.22.1 does not write content to custom access.logs

Tags: nginx, logging

I installed nginx 1.22.1. It does write it's access.log as set in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf but when it comes to an additional setting in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf nginx does **not** continue logging.

I checked permissions (see below) and they seem OK. I've no idea why nginx does write one log whereas it does not fill the other.

Can anybody pls give me some hint where to search?

Thx

```
nginx -v
nginx version: nginx/1.22.1

cat /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
server {

    listen       80;
    server_name  www.knowscore.de;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/default-access-logs.log;

    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    add_header Proxy pi5;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8008;
    }

}

ls -al /var/log/nginx/
total 16
drwxr-xr-x  2 www-data www-data 4096 Nov 17 07:59 .
drwxr-xr-x 12 root     root     4096 Nov 16 16:03 ..
-rw-r-----  1 www-data www-data 4035 Nov 17 08:19 access.log
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data    0 Nov 17 07:59 default-access-logs.log
-rw-r-----  1 www-data www-data   78 Nov 16 16:03 error.log
```

Comment: Use `nginx -T` (uppercase -T` ) to view the entire configuration across all included files. Is there another `server` block? Check the `access.log` and `error.log`. Have you restarted Nginx since creating `default-access-logs.log` or did Nginx create the file itself?

Comment: `nginx -T` says `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf` **is** loaded. And nginx got restarted, wrote `default-access-logs.log` but does **not** write to it. So permissions seem OK and I don't know where to look what for.

Comment: So `nginx` does **not** write to a file (`default-access-logs.log`), created by itself. Although `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf` is loaded, it is **very** suspicious. The additional header `Proxy` does **not** appear in server's response (checked via `curl localhost -v`)

Answer (score 0):

`/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf` held a first configuration (above) that apparently got overwritten by `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` - both contained a **`server`**-block that listened to port `80`. Moving the first file to the second made `nginx` operate as expected.